# C programming: I have an error in creating a binary search tree using C

Tags: c, data-structures

I need to create a c program for BST but I can't create left child or right child for the root node. Creation of root node is ok. I can also search the element in the root node. But Can't add more than one element in the tree
Please help me solve this problem, kindly explain about the mistake that I made

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
typedef struct tree
{
    struct tree *left;
    int data;
    struct tree *right;
}node;
node *ROOT;
//////////////////////////
void *bud()
{
    return (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
}
/////////////////////
void createNode(int data, node *ptr)
{
    if(ptr==NULL)
    {
        ptr=bud();
        ptr->data=data;     
        ptr->left=NULL;
        ptr->right=NULL;
        ROOT=ptr;
        ptr=NULL;
        printf("DONE");
        return;
    }
    else if(data==ptr->data)
    {
        printf("Duplication not possible");
        return;
    }
    else if (data<ptr->data)
    {
        //ptr=ptr->left;
        createNode(data,ptr->left);
    }
    else if (data>ptr->data)
    {
        //ptr=ptr->right;
        createNode(data,ptr->right);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("INVALID");
    }
}
//////////////////////////////////////
void search(int data,node *ptr)
{
    if(ptr==NULL)
    {
        printf("NOT FOUND");
        return;
    }
    else if (ptr->data==data)
    {
        printf("Item Found");
        return;
    }
    else if(data<ptr->data)
    {
        //ptr=ptr->left;
        search(data,ptr->left);
    }
    else if (data>ptr->data)
    {
        //ptr=ptr->right;
        search(data,ptr->right);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("INVALID");
    }
}
/////////////////////////////////
void main()
{
    int ch;
    ch=0;
    while (ch!=6)
    {
        printf("\nMENU\n1. Create Tree\n2. Search\n3. Inorder\n4. 
Preorder\n5. Postorder\n6. Exit\n EnterYour Choice:  ");
        scanf("%d",&ch);
        if(ch==1)
        {
            int dat;
            printf("\nEnter the number to be inserted: ");
            scanf("%d",&dat);
            createNode(dat,ROOT);
        }
        else if(ch==2)
        { 
            int dat;
            printf("Enter number to be searched: ");
            scanf("%d",&dat);
            search(dat,ROOT);
        }
        else if(ch==6)
        {
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("\nEnter a valid choice\n");
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is logical error. I can't create the left or right child of the tree. Whatever I insert to the tree gets inserted to the root node.

Comment: Show us your code (not a link) and the error you're getting

Comment: You should include the source inside the question. See [ask] and [mcve] about how to ask a good question so you maximize your chances of getting an answer.

Comment: Please post code, errors, sample data or textual output here as plain-text, not as external links that can expire or may be updated independently of the question, confusing the issue. Use the `{}` button to format any blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect.

Comment: Sorry this is my first time here. I have edited the question

Comment: Every time you are creating a node, you are assigning that to ROOT -> `ROOT=ptr;`. With this, you are losing the actual root of your tree.

Answer (score 1):

> I can't create the left or right child of the tree. Whatever I insert to the tree gets inserted to the root node.

This is happening because of this statement in your `createNode()`:

```
ROOT=ptr;
```

Whenever you are inserting an element in the tree, you are traversing tree recursively and when you find the appropriate location to insert, you are passing it to `createNode()` which is `NULL` (either ptr->left or ptr->right) and `ROOT` is reassigned to `ptr`.

If I just make changes in your program to make work it properly, the `createNode()` will look like this:

```
void createNode(int data, node **ptr)
{
    if(*ptr==NULL)
    {
        *ptr=bud();
        (*ptr)->data=data;
        (*ptr)->left=NULL;
        (*ptr)->right=NULL;
        printf("DONE");
        return;
    }
    else if(data==(*ptr)->data)
    {
        printf("Duplication not possible");
        return;
    }
    else if (data<(*ptr)->data)
    {
        createNode(data,&((*ptr)->left));
    }
    else if (data>(*ptr)->data)
    {
        createNode(data,&((*ptr)->right));
    }
    else
    {
        printf("INVALID");
    }
}
```

And in `main()`, you need to do:

```
createNode(dat,&ROOT);
```

However, there is a scope of improvement in your program, for e.g. separate the node `creation` and `insertion` operation in your program. I am leaving it up to you to find the improvements and better ways of theirs implementation.

Answer (score 0):

The error is in your `createNode()` function: you pass `node *ptr` and assign like this `ptr=bud();`. But this only modifies local variable, not pointer in parent node. Try passing `node **ptr` and do dereferencing inside of the function `*ptr=bud();`. Use & operator to derive pointer to pointer. As @H.S. mentioned `ROOT=ptr;` statement makes your program lose node. Besides you allocate memory and don't free it (you can't even do that, because you lose pointer to ROOT node).

Comment: or return the pointer to the new node